# Trace and if statement contradicting

Tags: flash, if-statement, trace

The first trace prints "2" yet the second trace "true" is never printed... I will show more code as requested but this just doesn't make any sense to me:

```
trace(n.wallMask & 2);
if (n.wallMask & 2 != 0) {
    trace(true);
    w = 22.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add brackets :

```
if ((n.wallMask & 2) != 0) {
    trace(true);
    w = 22.5;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. But could you tell me why it wouldn't work without the brackets?

Comment: @connor: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000726.html.

Comment: so != is considered in order of operations?